# bounded wildcards in java generics

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

I am reading `Core Java volume-1 by Horstmann, Cay.S` on `generics`. I am not able to understand some explanation of the text book. I give the sample code below which the author refers to. followed by the text from the book and my question.

```
 class Employees{ }

class Manager extends Employees { }

class Pair<T>{

    private T first;
    private T second;

    Pair(T first, T second){
        this.first=first;
        this.second=second;
    }


    void setFirst(T value){
        first=value;
    }

    T getFirst(){
        return first;
    }

}


public class WildCardGenerics {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        Manager ceo = new Manager();
        Manager cfo=new Manager();

        Employees clerk = new Employees();

        Pair<Manager> managers= new Pair<>(ceo,cfo);
        Pair<? extends Employees> employees=managers;

        employees.setFirst(clerk);



    }
    }
```

From the book:

"""No corruption is possible. The call to `setFirst` is a `type error`. To see why, let us have a closer
look at the type `Pair<? extends Employee>`. Its methods look like this:

```
? extends Employee getFirst()
void setFirst(? extends Employee)
```

This makes it impossible to call the `setFirst` method. The `compiler` only knows that it needs some `subtype` of `Employees`, but it doesn't know which type. It refuses to `pass any specific type` - after all
`?`might not match it."""

Question:
I do not understand why it refuses to pass any specific type. so what does this method accept?
`? extends Employee` -- means include Employee and any subtype of Employee. so passing an Employee should be legal correct?

From the book:

```
pair<? super Manager> has methods:
void setFirst(? super Manager)
? super Manager getFirst()
```

The compiler doesnt' know the exact type of the `setFirst` method and therefore can't call it
with an object of type `Employee or Object`, but only with `Manager` or a `subtype` such as `executive`.

Question:
So here I say the method can accept any Manager objects or that extends Manager object (similar to subytpe bound above). Not clear to me as why?

From the book:

`Intuitively speaking, wildcards with supertype bounds let you write to a generic object, while
wildcards with subtype bounds let you read from a generic object.`

Question:
I cannot follow it at all. It sounds simple,but not following the logic as what is meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assignment is legal, provided `Clerk` is an `Employees` [sic].

```
Pair<? extends Employees> employees = new Pair<Clerk>(clerk1, clerk2);
```

You shouldn't be able to call `setFirst` and pass a `Manager`, because here, it's really `Pair<Clerk>`.

This illustrates why Java doesn't allow calling a method with the generic type parameter in it (`T`) if there is a `? extends` wildcard.  The compiler doesn't know which class it really is - `Employee`?  A subclass?  Which subclass?  Due to type erasure, the JVM can't check for type safety, so the compiler must disallow all such calls with everything except `null`, which can be cast to any reference type and is always allowed.

With `? super Employee`, the lower bound is `Employee`.  It could be `Pair<Object>`.  But, passing an `Employee` or one of its subclasses is safe, because they are subclasses of anything allowed by `? super Employee`.

Comment: `This illustrates why Java doesn't allow calling a method with the generic type parameter in it (T) if there is a ? extends wildcard`-- so what is the purpose of having it, if it cannot be called?

Comment: You can still access elements from the pair, and have the guarantee that they're instances of Employee. Read the link you got about PECS. ? extends T allows getting information from the container. ? super T allows setting information inside the container. See [List.addAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28int,%20java.util.Collection%29) for a practical example. addAll can read all the elements from the collection passed as argument, but won't modify this list. So you can use addAll() on a List<Employee> and pass it a List<Clerk>.

Comment: @user1988876 You can refer to a `Pair<Employee>`, a `Pair<Manager>`, or a `Pair<Clerk>` with the same variable.  The price of that is that you can't call such methods and still preserve type safety.

Comment: so wildcards are most useful as method parameters rather than for simple assignments such as `List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();` correct? or what advantage does this assignment going to give, if I know `foo3` is going to be a `ArrayList<Integer>()`

Comment: There is no advantage to assigning an object of a class with a known type parameter to a variable with a wildcard.  As you can see now, it's restrictive.  It is more advantageous to provide it as a parameter to a method, so that the method is more flexible, by accepting a wider range of types.

Answer (score 1):

Always read `? extends T` as "some `CAP#1` extending `T`", and `? super T` as "some `CAP#2` that `T` extends".

Now your examples are more readable:

"No corruption is possible. The call to setFirst is a type error. To see why, let us have a closer look at the type `Pair< some CAP#1 extending Employee >`. Its methods look like this:

```
CAP#1 getFirst()
void setFirst( CAP#1 value )
```

Since `CAP#1` is a made-up type, you can't call `setFirst()` with an `Employee`, because you can't know if `CAP#1` is `Employee` or some random subtype of it.  `setFirst()` is a *contravariant* method; it *consumes* instances of the generic type.

However, no matter what `CAP#1` is, it extends `Employee`, so you *can* call `getFirst()` and assign the result to an `Employee`-typed variable.  `getFirst()` is *covariant*; it *produces* instances of the generic type.

So you ask, why on earth would you ever want a variable of type `Pair< ? extends Employee >`, if you can't use half the methods on such a variable?

Because the one thing you *can* do with wildcard types is get around some of the variance issues in Java.  Whether I have a `Pair< Employee >` or a `Pair< Manager >` or a `Pair< SomeClassExtendingManager >`, I can assign that thing to a variable of type `Pair< ? extends Employee >`.  I cannot assign a `Pair< Manager >` to a variable of type `Pair< Employee >`, even if `Pair` has no contravariant methods in it, because the type system can't figure that out.